# Solving for x when it appears with and without an exponent

Tags: functions

I have the following equation: $y = x + 0.489*(x^.89)$ and would like to solve for $x$. I am stuck because of how $x$ appears with the exponent and without the exponent. How can I isolate $x$ so that the equation is in terms of $y$? Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure there's not going to be an elementary solution to this. Equations like this one are hard to solve analytically. Even something like $y=x+3x^5$ is intractable, and we usually settle for numeric approximations.

Comment: You can let $w = \sqrt{100}{x}$ and get $y = w^{100} + 0.489w^{89} = w^{89}(w^{11} + 0.489)$ but I don't think that will make anything any easier.

Comment: @fleablood you mean $x=w^{100}$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  I meant $w =\sqrt[100]{x}$ and therefore $x = w^{100}$.  Mathjax.  I wrote \$\sqrt{100}{x}\$ instead of \$\sqrt[100]{x}$ as I meant.

Comment: $y=f(x)$ is odd ($f(x)=-f(-x)$) and over the open interval $(-1,1)$ the function $f$ is almost equal to the identity. What else? Anyway $f$ is an homeomorphism of $\mathbb R$ and the inverse $f^{-1}$ exists.

Answer (score 2):

As said, you face a polynomial of degree $89$ and only numerical methods would do the job.

As soon as $x >1$ the function will vary very fast. So a reasonable starting point for Newton method would by $x_0=\min (1,y)$ for small values of $y$.

If large values of $y$, it would be better to look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=\log(x+0.489x^{89})-\log(y)$$ and use as a starting guess
$$x_0=\left(\frac y {0.489}\right)^{\frac 1 {89}}$$

Let us try for $y=1.2345$. Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.00000000 \\
 1 & 0.99428360 \\
 2 & 0.99232743 \\
 3 & 0.99214532 \\
 4 & 0.99214389
\end{array}
\right)$$

Trying for $y=123.45$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.0641205 \\
 1 & 1.0640170
\end{array}
\right)$$

Trying for $y=12345$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.1206312 \\
 1 & 1.1206301
\end{array}
\right)$$